# How to convert an image in imageView to text and present that text in a textView in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, textview, imageview

I am doing a module in which I need to [take an image -> crop it -> convert it to text] . I have done till taking a photo and cropping it and presenting it in imageView . But I am unable to convert that image in imageView to text .

This is the code :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
                //get the Uri for the captured image
                Uri uri = picUri;
                //carry out the crop operation
                performCrop();
                Log.d("picUri", uri.toString());

            }

            else if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST){
                picUri = data.getData();
                Log.d("uriGallery", picUri.toString());
                performCrop();
            }

            //user is returning from cropping the image
            else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){
                //get the returned data
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                //get the cropped bitmap
                Bitmap thePic = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                //display the returned cropped image
                imageView.setImageBitmap(thePic);

            }

        }
    }
```

So what else can I do after [image.setImageBitmap(thePic)] to convert it to text and present in a TextView. 
I tried using Google Vision API code after [image.setImageBitmap(thePic)] but unable to convert it to text.It was showing an error saying 
[jni_helper.cc:110 Bitmap is of the wrong format: 4]
[Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6]

So, how to solve this problem.

Comment: In order to better help answer your question, we prefer that your question demonstrate that you've tried to solve your problem yourself, with specific examples (usually code snippets) of what you've tried, and details of what problems and errors you've run into. Please consider editing your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OCR API for that.
This tutorial will help : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#0